# Swift Locations: Fire every X Meters a Notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, location, cllocationmanager

I hope you guys can help me, because my brain is burning from thinking :D.
I want to notify the user e.g. every 100 meter. But I don't want to change the refresh of the location service. There is a easy way but I'm not fine with it. I think there is a better solution. 
What I do so far (that's pseudo code!) This is called in didUpdateLocation

```
 //We want notify User but only 5 times during the movement
        if distanceToReport < settedDistance {
            //Store that first Notification is fired
            if !firstNotificationFired {
                self.notifyUser(report: report)

            }
            if firstNotificationFired && distanceToReport <= 400 {
                //Store that second Notification is fired
                self.notifyUser(report: report)
            } else if secondNotificationFired && distanceToReport <= 300 {
                //Store that third Notification is fired
            } else if thirdNotificationFired && distanceToReport <= 200 {
                //Store that fourth Notification is fired
            } else if fourthNotifiationFired && distanceToReport <= 100 {
                //Store that fifth Notification is fired
            }


        }
```

Is there a much better and efficent way than this? Or are there any mathematical or algorithm which may help?

Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way to clean up the code would be to put the distance into a variable and increment at each notification, should cut down on the if statements.

```
if notificationShouldFire && distanceToReport <= targetDistance {
   self.notifyUser(report: report)
   targetDistance += targetDistance + 100
   notificationShouldFire = true
   // could also use count variable rather than a variable for each notif.
   firedNotifications += firedNotifications + 1
}

// your if statement would change slightly
if firedNotifications <= 5 && distanceToReport <= targetDistance {
   // increment and notify here
}
```

I think you can make it slightly more efficient if you want, but what you have isn't the end of the world.